# set value `1` to a specific column for all tables in whole database?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

Our database have 450+ tables. Recently we have added `BusinessUnit int` column  to every table in the `Db` without default value `1`. Now we want to set `1` for `BusinessUnit` column in all tables existing row. Is there any way I can do this with single query? For single table it is very easy like below

```
update tablename set BusinessUnit=1
```

May be with the help of `sys.tables` and `sys.columns` we can do this in one query.

Or is it better to delete all `BusinessUnit column` and add again with default value ?

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Comment: The fact you have added this column to *every* table sounds like a flaw unto itself.

Comment: How did you add the column to 450 tables? Did you write a query for that?

Comment: *"Or is it better to delete all BusinessUnit column and add again with default value ?"* That depends. Do you plan to add a default constraint to the columns too?

Comment: @Salman it was done manually by our two intern developer they wrote alter scripts for each tables. I was thinking a way to make my life easy.

Comment: @Larnu No I do not want to add default constraint to the column. I just want `businessunit` 1 for all existing row. We are making our application support multi business unit so we added `businessunit` .

Comment: I'd do a `SELECT DISTINCT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'BusinessUnit'` and copy the results in a text file and convert it to `UPDATE <tablename> SET BusinessUnit = 1 WHERE BusinessUnit IS NULL`

Comment: The you'll want to `UPDATE` all the rows, @NagibMahfuz . `DROP`ing them, and then recreating them with a `DEFAULT` value would create them with a `DEFAULT CONSTRAINT`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly let's start with *real* the problem you have here. The fact that you have added the *same* column to every table in your database is most certainly a flaw. There is no way you need this column on *every* table, for every row. It could *very* easily introduce referencial integrity problems. For example, you've added the value to every table, and these tables, presumably, have relationships. So what happens when you update the value of the column `BusinessUnit` in `TableX` to `2`, but don't for *all* the rows it's related to in `TableA` `TableB` and `TableZ`? Then you have a "parent" row that is related to one `BusinessUnit`  and a "child" row related to a different one. this is very likely not desired or expected behaviour.

Most like the column should be added to just a few tables, whuch tables we don't know (we know nothing about your design) but most likely at the lowest point in the relationship. Then if you need to know what `BusinessUnit` is related to you would ensure your query `JOIN`s to the relevant table to find out what `BusinessUnit` the row belongs to (or perhaps use an `EXISTS` depending on your design).

That being said, you can do this, but it's likely not going to be quick, and will be costly. It certainly won't address the refernencial integrity issues I spoke about above. To do it, you would need to use dynamic SQL. Asd we are update 450~ tables, I wrap each `UPDATE` in it's own transaction, so that as the process runs through it doesn't end up locking **every single one** of your tables. I also *assume* you are on a supported version of SQL Server, and thus have access to `STRING_AGG`. If you don't use the old `FOR XML PATH` method.

```sql
DECLARE @SQL nvarchar(MAX),
        @CRLF nchar(2) = NCHAR(13) = NCHAR(10);

SELECT @SQL = STRING_AGG(
              N'BEGIN TRANSCATION;' + @CRLF +
              N'    UPDATE ' + QUOTENAME(s.[name]) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(t.[name]) + @CRLF +
              N'    SET ' + QUOTENAME(c.[name]) + N' = 1;' + @CRLF +
              N'COMMIT;',@CRLF)
FROM sys.schemas s
     JOIN sys.tables t ON s.schema_id = t.schema_id
     JOIN sys.columns c ON t.object_id = c.object_id
WHERE c.[name] = N'BusinessUnit';

--Your best friends
--PRINT @SQL;
--SELECT @SQL;

EXEC sys.sp_executesql @SQL;
```

Comment: Yes I understand now. `Businessunit` column is not needed for every table as there are lots of table with master and details concept and relation between them. Only for master table I need `Businessunit` .

Comment: I am accepting this one as the question is related to `sql-server`. But both works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Not really, you will have to generate dynamic SQL or just script it.

I normally select the tables from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA` (or `sys.tables`) then copy that into Excel and generate an `UPDATE` statement (or whatever) using a formula. Copy that into Management studio & press go.

Comment: Yes it works selecting all tables name from `sys.tables`. then I was able to generate update script in excel. Excel formula is like `= "update "&CelladdressOftablename&" set BusinessUnit=1"`